# How to join multiple RDDs in pyspark without converting to DF

Tags: join, pyspark, rdd

I have three RDDs (x,y,z) which I want to join. The first element of all three RDDs is the key which will be used for join.

I know how to join two:

```
rdd1 = x.map(lambda r: (r[0], r[1:]))
rdd2 = y.map(lambda r: (r[0], r[1:]))
rdd1_rdd2 = rdd1.join(rdd2)
```

How can I join the third RDD, z, to rdd1_rdd2?

Answer (score 5):

Just add another join and flatten the result:

```
rdd1_rdd2.join(rdd3).mapValues(lambda x: x[0] + (x[1], ))
```